# Fn::GetOptionSetting is not working in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am trying to edit environment configuration "JVMOptions" using beanstalk environment properties(or variables).

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    option_name: "JVM Options"
    value: '`{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace":"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment","OptionName": "VAR_JVMOPTION"}}`'
```

also tried this

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    option_name: "JVM Options"
    value:
      "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
        Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: "VAR_JVMOPTION"
```

Did any one passed the environment variables in option_settings module of .ebextensions folder?

Comment: I'm trying to find out if `DefaultValue` is required or not and your question came up on google. Have you tried adding a default?  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-getoptionsetting for syntax, but it doesn't mention if the default is required or not.